# boost asio fail to bind port 80

Tags: iis, port, bind, boost-asio

My application is written in c++ thanks to boost asio library, with classical methods:

```
acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol());
acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true));
acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
acceptor_.bind(endpoint);
acceptor_.listen();
```

On same machine, iis is running for a classic website.

I can't bind endpoint on port 80 in same time website is running. When i put a other port for binding, all is ok. It would be 
Is there an issue for usin website and asio binding on same port?

Thanks for help me ...

Answer (score 0):

IIS binds to port 80 by default. so that you cannot bind. If you want to bnd to port 80, stop IIS.